# How to get thumbnail of an image in ejabberd

Tags: file, erlang, thumbnails, ejabberd, mnesia

I uploaded a image/video on ejabberd server using my client and ejabbered in its response sends a url where that image resides.Now client triggers a request on that url and file download starts.What i want to do is basically first send the client a low quality thumbnail(So that if a video is very large and takes time to download ,in that time client will show that blurred image(As in whats app)).How to create this Thumbnail?Any idea?

Comment: now ejabberd update 15.10 and it support to create thumbnail , you can review mod_http_upload

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me this is a purely client side protocol. Just have the client passing the download information have a link to thumbnail URL as well.

Comment: Should something be installed server-side?